# Vim behavior differences in Server VS Desktop

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, vim

I work on a number of different server version 10, 12 & 14 and use Vim extensively with only the default options and no special settings. I just deployed a small PC with Ubuntu Desktop 15 and the Vim behavior is drastically different in *Insert mode*:

- The arrow keys insert special characters
- I can only backspace over characters I inserted in the current insert "session?"

  - i.e enter insert mode -> type a few chars -> I can backspace over them, but I cannot backspace over any other chars that exist there.
- files are not auto colorized

  - ie: html files, system files like `/etc/passwd`

These are only of the few inconsistencies. Is there any way I can get the desktop unit to behave like the server units in Vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `vim` version that comes with desktop is somewhat restricted, different; it is called [vim-tiny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074666/3701431). I had to run `sudo apt-get install vim` to get the simple arrow key behavior and other features. That's probably the simplest approach.

However, the second simplest thing that you can do is to copy over `vimrc` file from server to your desktop. You c an use either `rsync` or `scp`, whichever you're familiar with more to pull the file from server to local system.

Alternatively, you could search for customized `vimrc` files on github. There are plently of those with tons of customizations and features, which include your desired behavior and more

You can also have your own github account and back up the same vimrc file there. On each desktop install just `git clone https://github.com/YourRepo` and you will have that `vimrc` in the `YourRepo` folder.

Comment: You mean the default `vi` version ... ?

Comment: @A.B. yes, default. It's called `vim-tiny`

Comment: @Serg Thanks for that, just the install of standard vim did it. funy that when I ran vim -v it showed the exact version as the server showed without indicating it was vim-tiny